# Rake Aborted syntax error Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I've started learning Ruby on Rails using http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.  I'm by no means new to programming but Ruby on Rails is different to what I'm used to.

I'm on step 5 where I need to create a new article resource. When I modify the config/routes.rb file to look like this:

```
Blog2::Application.routes.draw do
get "welcome/index"

Blog2::Application.routes.draw do

resources :posts 


# The priority is based upon order of creation:
# first created -> highest priority.

# Sample of regular route:
#   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
# Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

# Sample of named route:
#   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
# This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

# Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
#   resources :products

# Sample resource route with options:
#   resources :products do
#     member do
#       get 'short'
#       post 'toggle'
#     end
#
#     collection do
#       get 'sold'
#     end
#   end

# Sample resource route with sub-resources:
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments, :sales
#     resource :seller
#   end

# Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments
#     resources :sales do
#       get 'recent', :on => :collection
#     end
#   end

# Sample resource route within a namespace:
#   namespace :admin do
#     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
#     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
#     resources :products
#   

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
# just remember to delete public/index.html.
#root :to => 'articles#new'


 root :to => 'welcome#index'

end
```

I keep getting an error in rake routes and it says:

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: C:/rubygems/blog2/config/routes.rb:68: syntax error, unexpected $en
d, expecting keyword_end
C:in execute_if_updated' C:/rubygems/blog2/config/environment.rb:5:in'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I know it's line 68 and has something to do with "end" but I've made sure the "end" is uncommented.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: There's obviously more in your file than a handful of lines. That block example is syntactically valid, but your actual file is not.

Comment: The error message says that error occurs in line number 68 of your `config/routes.rb` file. Show all content from this file.

Comment: Check your whole `routes.rb` file for a block that's not properly formed. Line 68 is just where Ruby was no longer able to make sense out of the file syntactically. But the error could be anywhere before that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call method `Blog2::Application.routes.draw` twice, each time starting block. Though you close only one of these blocks. The solution is to remove 4th line of `routes.rb` file (`Blog2::Application.routes.draw do`).

Comment: That works! 

Thanks.  I know my question was pretty daft...but I'm new to Ruby and it's a different concept to what I'm used to.